# express unit testing, calling close on server results in `call of undefined`

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, nodeunit

I am attempting to test drive an node.js application based on express.  I want to return a simple 404.html, which I can successfully do, but afterward, calling close on the node http server gets this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

I am having a hard time tracking down what is `undefined` because the same method works beautifully when called elsewhere.

Here is my express code:

```
function Server() {
    this.port = 9000;
    this.staticDir = '/public';
}

function handleHomeRequest(req, res) {
    var body = '<html><body>Home Page.</body></html>';
    res.send(body);
}

Server.prototype.start = function () {
    expServer = express();

    expServer.get('/', function (req, res) { handleHomeRequest(req, res); });
    expServer.use(function (req, res) {
        res.status(404).sendfile('./src/public/404.html');
    });

    runningServer = expServer.listen(this.port);
};

Server.prototype.stop = function (cb) {
    runningServer.close(cb);
};
```

Here is my nodeunit test code:

```
var ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost',
    PORT = 9000,
    URL = ROOT_URL + ':' + PORT + '/',
    http = require('http'),
    Server = require('./server.js'),
    server;

exports.setUp = function(done) {
    server = new Server();
    done();
};

exports.tearDown = function (done) {
    server = null;
    done();
};

exports['Requesting a page that does not exist results in a 404.'] = function (test) {
    server.start();
    httpGet(URL + 'guaranteedNotToExistPage', function(res, data) {
        test.equal(404, res.statusCode, 'Requesting a page that dne did not return with a status code of 404.');
        test.ok(data.indexOf('404 Page Not Found') > -1, 'The 404 page was not returned.');
        //test.done();
        server.stop(test.done);
    });
};

function httpGet(url, callback) {
    var request = http.get(url),
        receivedData = '';
    request.on('response', function (response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            receivedData += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            callback(response, receivedData);
        });
    });
}
```

The result of the http get request come back, the failure only occurs when I call `server.stop(test.done);` however, stopping the server is required to ensure my unit tests can be run in any order and independent.

Comment: How about using `this.runningServer` in both places to store the state in the object instead?

Comment: I think the runningServer suggestion is to simply not start and stop the server, the problem is that I need to test it statelessly. Any other ideas? Am I understanding your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First, where runningServer is defined? I can't see a

```
var runningServer;
```

anywhere in the first peace of code.
So, if you write a value in prototype.start I doubt you can access it on prototype.stop that is a different scope.

Second, {expressListener}.close() in node 0.6 was just synchronous, they added the callback on the 0.8. So, check the node.js version to be sure that the {cb} is correctly handled.